# How to add slick carousel to Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I am basically trying to add this onto the site

```
https://codepen.io/pnmcosta/pen/GYpxgr
```

Placing that on one of the components and it gives the following error

```
render function or template not defined in component: FirstPageSecondSection
```

Basically just adding that onto the script,style and template

Here is one of the example when I added the script

```
<script>
export default {
    data:() =>({
        
    })
}
    $(function() {
  $('.slider-services').slick({
    dots: true,
    appendDots: '.slider-dots',
    arrows: true,
        infinite: false,
        slidesToScroll: 3,
        slidesToShow: 3,
        accessibility: true,
        variableWidth: false,
        focusOnSelect: false,
        centerMode: false,
        responsive: [
            {
                breakpoint: 992,
                settings: {
                    slidesToScroll: 2,
                    slidesToShow: 2
                }
            },
            {
                breakpoint: 600,
                settings: {
                    slidesToScroll: 1,
                    slidesToShow: 1
                }
            }
        ]
  });
});  
</script>
```

I am new on Nuxtjs and hoping for an enlighment from the seniors.

Comment: The given code is incorrect because it is not nested anywhere. I fixed it on my answer. Even tho, I still do not recommend using slick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one is using [slick carousel](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/). It is based on jQuery. Since you're using VueJS, I do recommend to use any other carousel than trying to use some imperative hacky code.
VueJS is declarative, hence not relying on jQuery (imperative) may be a good idea. Also, VueJS is enough by itself to not bring a whole jQuery on top of your code base (more JS for nothing really).

Here is a whole list of carousels that you can use: https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue#carousel

I found and used [vue-silentbox](https://silentbox.silencesys.com/), [not the smallest](https://bundlephobia.com/package/vue-silentbox@2.4.5) but doing it's job well.

I've used it on [this website](https://our-friends.netlify.app/), click on an image and you'll see the carousel.
A code example can be found here: https://github.com/kissu/pet-friends/blob/master/src/views/Home.vue#L26

---

Formatted and modified code of OP, this one by itself is not working because we need to define jQuery too (otherwise `$` will be undefined). Still, **NOT** a solution that I do recommend.

```html
<script>
export default {
  mounted() {
    $(function () {
      $('.slider-services').slick({
        dots: true,
        appendDots: '.slider-dots',
        arrows: true,
        infinite: false,
        slidesToScroll: 3,
        slidesToShow: 3,
        accessibility: true,
        variableWidth: false,
        focusOnSelect: false,
        centerMode: false,
        responsive: [
          {
            breakpoint: 992,
            settings: {
              slidesToScroll: 2,
              slidesToShow: 2,
            },
          },
          {
            breakpoint: 600,
            settings: {
              slidesToScroll: 1,
              slidesToShow: 1,
            },
          },
        ],
      })
    })
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hi @kissu , are you still using this plugin? vue-silentbox? Can you recommend a plugin that could help me display components within the carousel and slide through them?

Comment: @AlexandruAna I used that one for a quick time only. You have plenty of choice on the Internet and can always give a look here: https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue#carousel (as initially written in my answer)