# how to use scroll event listener in vue nuxt ts for specific div

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I know it is very possible with nuxt js. But how we can do this with nuxt and ugly ts? Convert this code into the terms of script lang ts if anyone will be able to do that. It's impossible as for nuxt there is near to no content on scroll event listening over a specific div attached example https://codepen.io/ash_0001/pen/NWMYaOw

```
    new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    loading: false,
    nextItem: 1,
    items: []
  },
  mounted () {

    
    const listElm = document.querySelector('#infinite-list');
    listElm.addEventListener('scroll', e => {
      if(listElm.scrollTop + listElm.clientHeight >= listElm.scrollHeight) {
        this.loadMore();
      }
    });

 
    this.loadMore();

  },
  methods: {
    loadMore () {
      
      
      this.loading = true;
      setTimeout(e => {
        for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
          this.items.push('Item ' + this.nextItem++);
        }
        this.loading = false;
      }, 200);
   
      
    }
  }
});
```

This is my package.json file

```json
{
  "name": "web_portal",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt-ts",
    "build": "nuxt-ts build",
    "start": "nuxt-ts start",
    "generate": "nuxt-ts generate",
    "lint:js": "eslint --ext .js,.vue --ignore-path .gitignore .",
    "lint:style": "stylelint **/*.{vue,css} --ignore-path .gitignore",
    "lint": "yarn lint:js && yarn lint:style"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@bachdgvn/vue-otp-input": "^1.0.8",
    "@morioh/v-msg": "^1.0.4",
    "@nuxt/content": "^1.9.0",
    "@nuxt/typescript-runtime": "^2.0.0",
    "@nuxtjs/auth-next": "5.0.0-1608568767.2fe2217",
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.12.4",
    "@nuxtjs/pwa": "^3.0.2",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.14.0",
    "@vue-stripe/vue-stripe": "^4.1.8",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "nuxt": "^2.14.6",
    "nuxt-property-decorator": "^2.8.8",
    "nuxt-socket-io": "^2.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxt/types": "^2.14.6",
    "@nuxt/typescript-build": "^2.0.3",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-config": "^3.1.0",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-config-typescript": "^3.0.0",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-module": "^2.0.0",
    "@nuxtjs/moment": "^1.6.1",
    "@nuxtjs/stylelint-module": "^4.0.0",
    "@nuxtjs/vuetify": "^1.11.2",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "cypress": "7.1.0",
    "eslint": "^7.10.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-nuxt": "^1.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.4",
    "prettier": "^2.1.2",
    "stylelint": "^13.7.2",
    "stylelint-config-prettier": "^8.0.2",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "^20.0.0",
    "video.js": "^7.11.8"
  }
}
```

Comment: Which version of Nuxt are you using here? v2 or v3? There is no content on that specific subject because it's too specific and not related to Nuxt per-se. Do you want to have an infinite scroll type of feature here?

Comment: Something like this? https://our-friends.netlify.app/

Comment: First of all, thank you very very much for replying to me I was sleeping 7 hours ago as the dev needed at least 6 hours of sleep and 1hour to clean himself. Duties apart, I added my package.json. Yeah kind of friends application but for specific div means that the whole system lies inside the div I also attached the prototype of codepen with js/vue

Comment: If you're on Nuxt2, don't bother with TS. It will not bring you any benefit if you don't know how to use it efficiently anyway (IMO), will just be a thing slowing you down. As for an infinite scroll implementation, you may have several approaches from which, this is a viable answer (+ working project) here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68981901/8816585 Here is another package used in a Vue context: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68101822/8816585 Finally, if you want some implementation without any package, you can check this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68265585/8816585

Comment: 2 other recommendations: don't use momentJS (better alternatives listed on their website) + don't use querySelectors, prefer template refs for selecting specific pieces of your DOM in Vue.

Comment: Thank you very much for replying to me. So is that event listening is possible in nuxt or not for a particular div with ts? The problem is my nuxt store code is written in ts and it is around 300 lines. And I don't know who the piece of shit started this project with nuxt and ts. And from where he gets inspiration to do so. What I can do please help. As such, there is an API with which I have to work. And it changes based on multiple selectors then an API got appended and then fetches requests and then for page 2 I want to load it for the second page.

Comment: And I am also not sure if I converted the store to js using my valuable time and then things will go good or not (I hope they should but I want some senior people's suggestions)

Comment: But really @kissu you are the kindest guy till now I ever met in StackOverflow. I will keep the flow.

Comment: I don't recommend event listeners at all, either use a package or Intersection API. Better to rely on state than on eventListeners in an SPA context overall. Checking for a specific element in your template is still totally feasible (as shown in the links I gave) with either a specific component or template refs. If you have a part in TS, you can keep it: no need to have your whole project in TS (TS is optional for every file). You can also gently remove TS from your store of course. Yeah, infinite scroll + paginated API is what I have in my examples too. Consider using an ESlint configuration

Comment: Key takeaways: a) I have to use a package or Intersection API. b) State(means data() function have to use instead of event listeners) c) I can change my particular store code to js it won't affect the other store codes or any part{Ultimately I can work on that} d) And via that, I can use your examples to build scroll to load functionality. and e) kissu is the most kindest guy in Stackoverflow

Comment: a. yeah, consider [that package](https://github.com/Akryum/vue-observe-visibility) if you want full flexibility while having an easy time working with the Intersection Observer API. or any other cools packages [from here](https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue), make a search on the page. b. Vue uses state to trigger it's reactivity. The "state" here is used in a broader meaning (computed, data, store, method etc...) it's opposed to DOM changes like in jQuery (imperative). c. yes! (depends of the configuration of the project's TS rules of course) d. yeah, those can be a great start indeed!

Comment: Thank you very much From the Bottom of my heart

Comment: Mind if I post an answer of some sort or do you prefer to wait until you have a working infinite scroll?

Comment: I completely give this authorization to you. If You will post anything. I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: Alright, just did!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want some easy to use infinite scroll implementation, I recommend giving a try to [vue-observe-visibility](https://github.com/Akryum/vue-observe-visibility) package.
Otherwise, you can also of course implement it with some vanilla implementation using the Intersection Observer API as [showcased here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73898887/how-to-use-scroll-event-listener-in-vue-nuxt-ts-for-specific-div#comment130496125_73898887).

The rest of your questions are answered in the comments above.